# Redirecting does not work properly, htaccess ignore my IP

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

here my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Rewrite to comingsoon
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=91.75.39.77
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/comingsoon\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|js) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /comingsoon.html [R=302,L]
```

The visitor with correct IP will ignored and redirected.
What is wrong with the code, does someone notice what?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK that make a trick
    `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !=91.75.39.77`